# Unable to call an activity using an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to call an activity from my mainactivity, but it is crashing an I cannot figure out why.

I call the activity from my mainactivity using a button as follows

```
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShapeScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);   
    }
});
```

This then opens up an activity with code as follows, which should just bring up the layout shapesscreen.xml (which has no errors in it)

```
public class ShapeScreen extends Activity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.shapescreen);
   }
}
```

The second activity is defined in my manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="Cubic Measurement" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".ShapeScreen"
    android:label="Cubic Measurement" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="kurt.steveboss.shapescreen" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But when I click this button the app crashes and I get the following error in my LogCat

```
 01-02 15:03:37.550: I/InputReader(2100): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, pending(waiting finished signal)=0, s=]
 01-02 15:03:37.550: I/InputDispatcher(2100): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
 01-02 15:03:37.550: I/InputDispatcher(2100): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
 01-02 15:03:37.550: I/InputDispatcher(2100): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
 01-02 15:03:37.555: I/ActivityManager(2100): START {intent.toShortString} from pid 8045
 01-02 15:03:37.555: I/power(2100): *** acquire_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1  freq : 1000000 
 01-02 15:03:37.555: D/PowerManagerService(2100): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1000000  uid : 1000  pid : 2100  tag : ActivityManager
 01-02 15:03:37.555: W/ActivityManager(2100): mDVFSLock.acquire()
 01-02 15:03:37.570: D/ActivityManager(2100): Trying to launch applicationName
 01-02 15:03:37.580: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2100): setHidden false
 01-02 15:03:37.650: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 22K, 2% free 18560K/18887K, paused 10ms
 01-02 15:03:37.655: I/dalvikvm-heap(8045): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.095MB for 2903056-byte allocation
 01-02 15:03:37.680: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 2% free 21393K/21767K, paused 1ms+1ms
 01-02 15:03:37.765: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 21394K/21767K, paused 9ms
 01-02 15:03:37.770: I/dalvikvm-heap(8045): Grow heap (frag case) to 23.864MB for 2903056-byte allocation
 01-02 15:03:37.790: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 24229K/24647K, paused 1ms+2ms
 01-02 15:03:37.875: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 24231K/24647K, paused 10ms
 01-02 15:03:37.880: I/dalvikvm-heap(8045): Grow heap (frag case) to 26.634MB for 2903056-byte allocation
 01-02 15:03:37.900: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 27066K/27527K, paused 2ms+2ms
 01-02 15:03:37.985: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 27067K/27527K, paused 9ms
 01-02 15:03:37.995: I/dalvikvm-heap(8045): Grow heap (frag case) to 29.404MB for 2903056-byte allocation
 01-02 15:03:38.015: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 29902K/30407K, paused 1ms+1ms
 01-02 15:03:38.095: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 29904K/30407K, paused 9ms
 01-02 15:03:38.105: I/dalvikvm-heap(8045): Grow heap (frag case) to 32.174MB for 2903056-byte allocation
 01-02 15:03:38.125: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 32739K/33287K, paused 1ms+1ms
 01-02 15:03:38.210: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 32741K/33287K, paused 10ms
 01-02 15:03:38.220: I/dalvikvm-heap(8045): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.944MB for 2903056-byte allocation
 01-02 15:03:38.235: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 35576K/36167K, paused 2ms+2ms
 01-02 15:03:38.315: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 35578K/36167K, paused 9ms
 01-02 15:03:38.325: I/dalvikvm-heap(8045): Grow heap (frag case) to 37.714MB for 2903056-byte allocation
 01-02 15:03:38.340: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 38413K/39047K, paused 2ms+2ms
 01-02 15:03:38.415: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 38414K/39047K, paused 10ms
 01-02 15:03:38.430: I/dalvikvm-heap(8045): Grow heap (frag case) to 40.485MB for 2903056-byte allocation
 01-02 15:03:38.445: D/dalvikvm(8045): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 41249K/41927K, paused 2ms+2ms
 01-02 15:03:38.555: I/power(2100): *** release_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1 
 01-02 15:03:38.555: D/PowerManagerService(2100): releaseDVFSLockLocked : all DVFS_MIN_LIMIT are released 
 01-02 15:03:38.555: W/ActivityManager(2100): mDVFSLock.release()
 01-02 15:03:38.975: W/PowerManagerService(2100): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x0
 01-02 15:03:38.975: I/PowerManagerService(2100): Ulight 0x7->0x3|0x0
 01-02 15:03:38.975: D/lights(2100): write_int /sys/class/sec/sec_touchkey/brightness = 2
 01-02 15:03:38.975: D/PowerManagerService(2100): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 0
 01-02 15:03:39.725: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2100): handleTimeout
```

Comment: If you're very keen on using your String action, you might want to see if the LogCat produces something useful.

Comment: The logcat snippet you posted has nothing related to the code snippets you posted.

Comment: Sorry, still learning to read the logcat properly. Have changed to logcat output that seems more relevant

Comment: See if anything in **red** outputs. It will probably also mention `[Something]Exception`

Comment: is this you complete logcat??

Comment: It turns out there was a bug with my Eclipse. Have downloaded a new version and thus the suggested answers below work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent("YOUR_ACTIVITY_CLASS.this,ShapeScreen.class");
                startActivity(i);   
            }
```

**Instead of**

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent("kurt.steveboss.shapescreen");
            startActivity(i);   
        }
```

Comment: I have added the code you suggested, but am still having the same problem. See updated code (with your suggestion) and updated logCat in edited question

Comment: **OK remove this from your menifest file:**

      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="kurt.steveboss.shapescreen" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `.class` approach to launch your Actvity.

```
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShapeScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);   
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have added the code you suggested, but am still having the same problem.

See updated code (with your suggestion) and updated logCat in edited question

Comment: @Kurt we need an actual logcat error to be able to help you. Try cleaning your project, all I can recommend.

Comment: Apologies for my naivety. So I clear the logcat, run the application. I click on the button and the usual "do you want to open the debug perspective because something has gone wrong" dialog box comes up in Eclipse.

I then open the logcat. If I go to all messages (no filter) then choose errors there are only two "!Sync 1306" and "!Sync 1307"

Is this what I should be looking at? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: So there is nothing red in the logcat? In that case open up a terminal/command prompt and type in `adb logcat`. You will get a lot of stuff but once the crash happens, just stop using the device and go back to your terminal. Copy the stack trace and post it (stack traces contain Class names, your Application's package & Class(es) will be part of it).

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't start a activity on your AndroidManifest.xml file in your application.You just try this code on your AndroidManifestfie

```
 <activity
 android:name=" .ShapeScreen" >
</activity>
```

now you can try this will work definitely